# Retrieving data from two tables.

Tags: sql, select

I have two (2) tables, **`users`** and **`warnings`**.

In **`users`**, I have three (3) columns: `uid`, `rank`, and `language`.

In **`warnings`**, I also have three (3) columns: `id`, `warnings`, and `warn_active`.

So my question is: How can i display all results in **phpmyadmin** where:

- `rank` = '2'
- `language` = 'en'
- `warn_active` = 'yes'

In both tables `uid`/`id` stands for user unique ID.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Show us something to help you. :-)

Comment: A simple INNER JOIN with 3 conditions.http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: this is for my site and im using phpmyadmin to browse the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Select u.*,w.* from users u inner join warnings w on u.uid == w.id 
 where u.rank=2 and u.language='en' and w.warn_active='yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

what kind of relationship do you have here between the two tables?
If you have Many to many.. then create a third table as follows

```
create table user_warnings(uid integer REFERENCES users(uid),id integer REFERENCES warnings(id));
```

insert the values of ids in the table users_warnings of the two ids in each table related to each other
then fire the below query

```
Select * from users,warnings,users_warnings where users.uid=users_warnings.uid and warnings.id=users_warnings.id and users.rank=2 and users.language='en' and warnings.warn_active='yes';
```

Let me knw if you encounter any error..

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u.uid,u.rank,u.language, w.warnings  from users u inner join warnings w on u.uid == w.id 
 where u.rank=2 and u.language='en' and w.warn_active='yes'
```